# FIFO function - manual approach

Tags: python, list, fifo

Python novice here. I am working on an assignment that has me a bit stumped.

The goal is set up a simple FIFO system, without using any imported libraries.

My attempt so far is incorrect and I am looking for some suggestions on how to fix it.

Attempt:

```
requests = [4, 32, 5, 8, 7, 4, 8] # Will be any random integer inputted by user, provided this list as an example
cache = []

def fifo():
    for page in requests: 
        if page not in cache:
            print(page, "miss")
            cache.append(page) # This isn't right but not sure where to add?
        if page in cache:
            print(page, "hit")
            cache.remove(page) # If a page is already in the cache, it doesn't need to be added again - not sure if this is correct either?
        if len(cache) > 4: # max size of cache = 4
            cache.pop(0) # Removes first indexed item until cache = 4 elements
    print(cache)
    return

# Each page should be printed as a hit/miss if included/not included in the cache
# Ignoring hits/miss being printed, the required output = print(cache) = [32, 5, 7, 8] 
# i.e. the most recent 4 requests, previously requested pages (e.g. 4) shouldn't be included
```

How should I go about correcting the above? Open to alternative suggestions as I appreciate the above is likely far away from the optimal solution.

Thanks

Comment: 'FIFO' usually stands for 'first in, first out', but your function seems to be trying to do a bit more, like de-duplication, and only remembering the most recent 4 items - please describe in more detail what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: `return` is not needed element of your function if you not intend to return any value from it. The execution will return to caller automatically.

Comment: Hi Grismar. I am looking for an output that is inclusive of 4 non duplicated elements. So the 4 most recent requests, disregarding any that have been requested before. The first elements in, are the first elements out until the cache list is equal to 4. Does that make sense? A hit/miss system was included as part of the brief in order to capture duplicated requests.
Thanks Marcin, noted that it is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the text in the comments at the bottom of your code, it would appear that this is closer to what is required:

```
def f(requests, cache):
    for page in requests:
        if page in cache:
            cache.remove(page)
            print(page, "hit")
        else:
            print(page, "miss")
        if len(cache) > 3:
            cache.pop(0)
        cache.append(page)


requests = [4, 32, 5, 8, 7, 4, 8]
cache = []
f(requests, cache)
print(cache)
```

If would make a bit more sense for the function to operate on individual 'pages' though (also showing an approach using a global cache):

```
cache = []
def f(page):
    global cache
    if page in cache:
        print(page, "hit")
        cache.remove(page)
    else:
        print(page, "miss")
    if len(cache) > 3:
        cache.pop(0)
    cache.append(page)


for page in [4, 32, 5, 8, 7, 4, 8]:
    f(page)


print(cache)
```

However, note that both these solutions show a different outcome than the question: `[5, 7, 4, 8]` instead of `[32, 5, 7, 8]`.

The question seems to get the answer wrong itself, unless the *actual* maximum cache size isn't 4, but 5. Consider this: how can the cache still contain `4`, when it most recently got `32`, `5`, `8`, and `7` and its size would be 4? So, when `4` comes around again, it has no memory of it and should update to `[5, 7, 4, 8]`. Where are you getting this assignment?

Also note that I wouldn't want to recommend using a global variable as in the second solution - however, all this seems to be a step up on the way to writing a `Cache` class of sorts, which would make the cache a variable internal to the class or object, instead of a global. Such a class could look like this:

```
class Cache:
    def __init__(self, size=4):
        self._size = size
        self._cache = []

    def hit(self, page):
        if (result := (page in self._cache)):
            self._cache.remove(page)
        if self._cache.__len__() == self._size:
            self._cache.pop(0)
        self._cache.append(page)
        return result

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._cache)


c = Cache(4)
for p in [4, 32, 5, 8, 7, 4, 8]:
    if c.hit(p):
        print('hit', p)
    else:
        print('miss', p)
print(c)
```

Comment: Hi Grismar. Many thanks for your answer/comments. Apologies for any confusion, the list of numbers is something I provided rather that the question so I imagine that's where the error comes into play. I will look into your answer now :)

Comment: I added an update, since my initial solution didn't really take your FIFO aspect into account, which it does now

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do that, much appreciated :)

Comment: Note my remark on the wrong  answer in the question itself though - you may need to give the original question a closer read, because it may have been misrepresented in what you shared (or it's actually wrong, in which case you'd be better off learning somewhere else).